# Python automatically changing all dictionary values

Tags: python, list, class

I've been working on a text based adventure game, in the process of doing the skeleton for the game building system. I got the movement working by typing NESW originally but after removing the debugging code, its been broken for over a day. Thought I would reach out for help...

Here's the main issue:
A grid is automatically generated with coordinate objects containing a dictionary value of places it "canGo" corresponding for a single letter key  and a bool, defaulted to False. After initializing the grid, I pass a list of coordinates I want to activate to the grid that executes the following function: (1)it activates all the grids in the list passed; (2)it runs a function that generates a list of active squares; (3)it passes that list to a function that checks one square away from each of the active coords and sees if it is active, if so then it marks that direction bool as True (example canGo["N"] = True.

Issue: (Debug below) the correctly sets the attributes when initializing, after completion the keys come back WRONG but were seemingly not set again to something else in my code. Further, it sets all of keys to the same thing (in this case all of the keys in all coords are ["S"] = True)

```
-SD--------
SETTING DIRECTIONG debug
(1, 1) >> N
-SD--------
(1, 1) directions = N
(1, 1){'N': True, 'S': False, 'E': False, 'W': False}
-------------------
-SD--------
SETTING DIRECTIONG debug
(1, 2) >> S
-SD--------
(1, 2) directions = S
(1, 2){'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'W': False}
-------------------
(1,1): {'N': False, 'S': True, 'E': False, 'W': False}
Which direction would you like to move? <NESW>:
```

Debug so far: I have debug code inside that shows me it correctly recognizes the activated grids, correctly passes them to the list, and that the list correctly sets the ["canGo"] coordinate attribute. No other code is executed after initializing and processing the activated coords and before it asks you what direction you would like to go.

**Code below...**

**Main**

```
from coordinates import Coordinates as Coords
from grid import Grid
from player import Player


def main():
    gridSizeX = 5
    gridSizeY = 5

    game = Grid(gridSizeX,gridSizeY, Player("John Doe", 1, 1))
    #game.setActiveGridSquares([(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)])
    game.grid[1][1].active = True
    game.grid[1][2].active = True
    game.grid[1][1].setDirections("N")
    game.grid[1][2].setDirections("S")

    while(True):
        x,y = game.player.getLocation()
        print("({x},{y}): {canGo}".format(x=x,y=y,canGo=game.grid[x][y].canGo))
        move = input("Which direction would you like to move? <NESW>: ")
        if(move.upper() == "EXIT"):
            break
        game.movePlayer(move.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Grid**

In here, I am passing an immutable list of tuples (x,y) that then iterates through, and breaks apart. Main processing of the directions in the error occurs under Grid class in directionsProcessing()

```
from coordinates import Coordinates as  Coords
from player import Player

class Grid:
    """Builds Grid and takes Player Object to move along grid"""
    playerLocation = None

    def __init__(self, gridSizeX, gridSizeY, player):
        self.grid = self.buildGrid(gridSizeX,gridSizeY)
        self.player = player

    def buildGrid(self, gridSizeX, gridSizeY):
        """Builds and returns a grid object as a dictionary of [x][y]
        Starts at 1 and ends at gridSize(X/Y)
        gridSize(X/Y) will be the (x/y) max. -> 5 would be 1 to 5
        """
        Grid = {}
        for x in range(1, gridSizeX+1):
            Grid[x] = {}
            for y in range(1, gridSizeY+1):
                Grid[x][y] = Coords(x, y)
        return Grid

    def copyGrid(self):
        """Returns a copy of grid dictionary"""
        return self.grid

    def setPlayer(self, playerToSet):
        """Sets player object into grid class to allow for player tracking"""
        self.player = playerToSet

    def setActiveGridSquares(self, squares):
        """Sets a list of grid squares to active"""
        for t in squares:
            x,y = t
            self.grid[x][y].isActive = True
        self.solveGridDirections(self.getAllActiveSquares())

    def getAllActiveSquares(self):
        """Returns list of all active grid squares"""
        activeGridSquares = []
        for x in self.grid:
            for y in self.grid[x]:
                if(self.grid[x][y].isActive):
                    activeGridSquares.append((self.grid[x][y].x,self.grid[x][y].y))
        return activeGridSquares

    def solveGridDirections(self, activeSquares):
        """Resolves all active grid squares direction components to
        allow movement into nearby active squares"""
        for t in activeSquares:
            adjoiningDirections = []
            x,y = t
            #print("Evaluating ActiveSquare: ("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
            if((x,y+1) in activeSquares):
                adjoiningDirections.append("N")
            if((x,y-1) in activeSquares):
                adjoiningDirections.append("S")
            if((x+1,y) in activeSquares):
                adjoiningDirections.append("E")
            if((x-1,y) in activeSquares):
                adjoiningDirections.append("W")
            self.grid[x][y].setDirections("".join(adjoiningDirections)) #Sets allowed move directions inside grid
            


    def movePlayer(self, direction):
        """Moves player in direction, preforms coordinate check if player can move"""
        if(len(direction) > 1):
            print("Lenght must be 1 character ONLY <NESW>")
            return
        x,y = self.player.getLocation()
        print("-MP-------------") #####
        print("({x},{y})Can I move in {direction} direction? {tf}".format(x=str(x),y=str(y),direction=direction,tf=str(self.grid[x][y].canGo[direction])))
        print("-MP-------------") #####
        if(self.grid[x][y].canGo[direction]):
            self.player.movePlayer(direction)
        else:
            print("Player cannot move in that direciton on this grid square.")
```

**Coordinates**

```
class Coordinates:
    """Set coordinates of path squards in the world"""

    actionOnEnter = None
    choices = {"a":None,"b":None,"c":None}
    canGo = {"N": False,"S": False,"E": False,"W": False}
    isActive = False

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x  #set x coords
        self.y = y  #set y coords

    def directionsProcessing(self, directions):
        """Directions are processed into a specific order and canGo is amended"""
        listOfDirections = ["N", "S", "E", "W"]
        verifiedDirections = []
        coordsDir = str(self.getCoords())
        print(coordsDir+" directions = "+directions) #####
        for m in listOfDirections:
            if(directions.find(m) != -1):
                self.canGo[m] = True
                verifiedDirections.append(m)
            else:
                self.canGo[m] = False
        print(coordsDir+str(self.canGo)) #####
        print("-------------------") #####

    def setDirections(self, direcitons):
        """Sets directions a player can move, updates from initialization"""
        print("-SD--------")#####
        coordsDir = str(self.getCoords())#####
        print("SETTING DIRECTIONG debug")#####
        print(coordsDir+" >> "+direcitons)#####
        print("-SD--------")#####
        self.directionsProcessing(direcitons)

    def getCoords(self):
        """Return x,y coordinate duple"""
        return self.x,self.y
```

**Player (less important but still plays a roll in motion)**

```
class Player:
    """Player class used to hold player data.
    X and Y coords are player's starting coordinates
    Control inventory, keys, etc.
    """
    inventory = {"sword": False}
    keys = {"rectangle": False, "half moon": False}

    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def movePlayer(self, direction):
        """Moves player toards certain coordinates, <NESW>"""
        if (len(direction) != 1):
            raise Exception("Only 1 letter may be used.")
        updown = {"N": 1, "S": -1, "W": -1, "E": 1}
        validDirections = ["N","S","E","W"]
        
        if(direction.upper() in validDirections):
            if (direction in ["N","S"]):
                self.y += updown[direction]
            if (direction in ["W","E"]):
                self.x += updown[direction]
        else:
            Exception("Direction is invalid")

    def getLocation(self):
        """Returns tuple of player location x,y"""
        return self.x,self.y

    def setLocation(self, locationTuple):
        """Sets location based on input tuple
        Syntax -> Player.setLocation((x,y))
        """
        x,y = locationTuple
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def toString(self):
        """Converts player data into string"""
        return "Player: {name} Location: {x},{y}".format(name=self.name, x=self.x, y=self.y)
```

Comment: Too much code for me; are you passing a mutable value (a list, set or dict) as a parameter, so the grid is all referring to that single mutable and ay change to the mutable is then of course visible in all grid locations?

Comment: I am passing an immutable list of tuples (x,y) that it then iterates through, and breaks apart. Main processing occurs under GRID in directionsProcessing()

Comment: It’s your code that’s doing this: looks to me like you’re mixing up class and instance attributes. You want `canGo` to be an instance attribute, so move it’s initialization from where it is in `Coord` (which makes it a class attribute, i.e. there’s only one value for it) to within the `__init__()` method as `self.canGo=…` Check the other class attributes you’ve got, see if they need similar treatment so they become instance attributes.

Comment: I’ve not tried this, but what I think is happening is that if `canGo` were immutable e.g. a string/integer/tuple then assigning to an instance `.canGo` would create an instance attribute with that value. However because `Coords.canGo` is mutable an instance writing to it updates the class attribute, so all instances see the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @barny for your help.

This can be solved in two ways after reading your comments

(1) [better] move canGo to the **init**() method

(2) create an empty instance of "canGoTemp" inside the directionsProcession() method and pass the values to that, then pass the dict to the canGo attribute (this is without moving canGo to **init**())

both of these worked but I landed on (1)...

Thanks again man, I know it was a mess

Comment: :-) Don’t understand your option 2 - my strong advice is to keep it simple/explicit: if your code needs an instance attribute then **make** it an instance attribute by initialising `self.canGo` in the __init__(). You need to give the same treatment to other class attributes you currently have; if you really want class attribute then make sure you reference them as e.g. `Coords.choices`. If you want/need to reference an attribute as `self.x` then you *must* (for your sanity) initialise them as `self.x`.